# JSX script to Photoshop action - Is it possible?

Tags: action, photoshop, extendscript

I wonder if there exist a method to convert a simple JSX script to an action.

I have created an action and converted it to jsx in order to clean and edit it. Now, I want to convert it back to atn in order to use a keybord shorcut.

PS: I did create an action (with ctrl+F12 assigned) that calls the script, but I'd like to have a not dependant action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy the JSX file into your Photoshop Script folder (PHOTOSHOP_INSTALL_FOLDER/Presets/Scripts).
For example:

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\Presets\Scripts
/Applications/Adobe Photoshop CC 2018/Presets/Scripts
```

Once your script is there, restart Photoshop and you see it under `File > Scripts` and you should be able assign keyboard shortcut to that easily using `Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> File (expand this) -> Scripts (expand this)`

Note: If you place text like this at the top of your .jsx file, YOUR DESCRIPTION will show up on the Scripts menu:

```
<javascriptresource>
<name>$$$/JavaScripts/YOURNAME/Menu=YOUR DESCRIPITION</name>
<category>Scripts</category>
</javascriptresource>
#target photoshop
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create an action to load the script. That's it.

You can do this by navigating Files>Scripts>Browse while recording an action, then you can assign Shortcut to it.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

record an action (with ctrl-f12 assigned) running the script.
The script needs to be in the above stated folder.

Comment: If you record an action, you can run the script from **anywhere**, it does not have to be in the Preset/Scripts folder - you just can't move it after making the recording.